# How to implement waterfall graph in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios5

I want to implement waterfall graph in iOS I searched on internet but did't find anything. I want something like below image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use core-plot library to draw graphs.

this libary have bar plot,you can set **barBaseValye** to **TRUE** for using bar plot as waterfall graph.

[coe-plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot)